# How to stop background jobs in subshell with infinite loop?

Tags: bash, scripting, tmux

In my `tmux` session over SSH, I ran:

```bash
( \
  ( while true; do echo subsubshell1 && sleep 5; done ) & \
  ( while true; do echo subsubshell2 && sleep 10; done ) & \
  wait; \
)
```

**How can I stop both background jobs without rebooting?** I have already run the command above, used <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd>, and closed the `tmux` pane. Suggestions on how to modify the command so I can close it easier when I run the command again next appreciated.

- `pkill sleep` just starts next iteration of loop.
- `fg` says no jobs
- <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd> only appears to stop the subshell, but not the sub-subshells and background commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processes for the loops are going to be called `bash`, sleep will just be a child process of them.  You can use `ps` to see which bash process are parent to the sleep processes:

```
$ ps -auf
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
jesse_b    255  0.0  0.0  10172  3248 pts/0    S    20:11   0:00 -bash
jesse_b    259  0.0  0.0   7232   580 pts/0    S    20:11   0:00  \_ sleep 10
jesse_b    254  0.0  0.0  10172  3248 pts/0    S    20:11   0:00 -bash
jesse_b    258  0.0  0.0   7232   520 pts/0    S    20:11   0:00  \_ sleep 5
jesse_b     13  0.0  0.0  10172  5252 pts/0    Ss   20:05   0:00 -bash
jesse_b    265  0.0  0.0  10856  3392 pts/0    R+   20:11   0:00  \_ ps -auf
```

In this case PIDs 254 and 255 are the bash processes you would need to kill.

Alternatively you could do something like this to echo out the PIDs for you:

```
( 
  ( while true; do echo subsubshell1 && sleep 5; done ) & 
  pids+=($!)
  ( while true; do echo subsubshell2 && sleep 10; done ) &
  pids+=($!)
  echo "${pids[@]}"
  wait
)
```